# lagrange approximation -c++

Tags: c++, numerical

I updated the code.
What i am trying to do is to hold every lagrange's coefficient values in pointer d.(for example for L1(x) d[0] would be "x-x2/x1-x2" ,d[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) would be (x-x2/x1-x2)*(x-x3/x1-x3) etc.

My problem is

1) how to initialize d ( i did  d[0]=(z-x[i])/(x[k]-x[i]) but i think it's not right the "d[0]"

2) how to initialize L_coeff. ( i am using L_coeff=new double[0] but am not sure if it's right.

The exercise is:
Find Lagrange's polynomial approximation for y(x)=cos(π x), x ∈−1,1 using 5 points
(x = -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, and 1).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double pi=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288;

// my function
double f(double x){

return (cos(pi*x));

}


//function to compute lagrange polynomial
double lagrange_polynomial(int N,double *x){
//N = degree of polynomial

double z,y;
double *L_coeff=new double [0];//L_coefficients of every Lagrange L_coefficient
double *d;//hold the polynomials values for every Lagrange coefficient
int k,i;
//computations for finding lagrange polynomial
//double sum=0;

for (k=0;k<N+1;k++){
        for ( i=0;i<N+1;i++){
            if (i==0) continue;
            d[0]=(z-x[i])/(x[k]-x[i]);//initialization
            if (i==k) L_coeff[k]=1.0;
            else if (i!=k){
            L_coeff[k]*=d[i];

                      }

           }

cout <<"\nL("<<k<<") = "<<d[i]<<"\t\t\tf(x)= "<<f(x[k])<<endl;
}

}

int main()
{

    double deg,result;
    double *x;


    cout <<"Give the degree of the polynomial :"<<endl;
    cin >>deg;

    for (int i=0;i<deg+1;i++){
    cout <<"\nGive the points of interpolation : "<<endl;
    cin >> x[i];
    }

    cout <<"\nThe Lagrange L_coefficients are: "<<endl;
    result=lagrange_polynomial(deg,x);



    return 0;
}
```

[Here is an example of lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

[image: This is the solution i have done]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this seems to be homework, I am not going to give you an exhaustive answer, but rather try to send you on the right track.

- How do you represent polynomials in a computer software? The *intuitive* version you want to archive as a symbolic expression like 3x^3+5x^2-4 is very unpractical for further computations.
- The polynomial is defined fully by saving (and outputting) it's coefficients.

What you are doing above is hoping that C++ does some algebraic manipulations for you and simplify your product with a *symbolic* variable. This is nothing C++ can do without quite a lot of effort.

You have two options:

- Either use a proper computer algebra system that can do symbolic manipulations (Maple or Mathematica are some examples)
- If you are bound to C++ you have to think a bit more how the single coefficients of the polynomial can be computed. You programs output can only be a list of numbers (which you could, of course, format as a nice looking string according to a symbolic expression).

Hope this gives you some ideas how to start.

### Edit 1

You still have an undefined expression in your code, as you never set any value to `y`. This leaves `prod*=(y-x[i])/(x[k]-x[i])` as an expression that will not return meaningful data. C++ can only work with numbers, and `y` is no number for you right now, but you think of it as symbol.

You could *evaluate* the lagrange approximation at, say the value `1`, if you would set `y=1` in your code. This would give you the (as far as I can see right now) correct function value, but no description of the function itself.

Maybe you should take a pen and a piece of paper first and try to write down the expression as precise Math. Try to get a real grip on what you want to compute. If you did that, maybe you come back here and tell us your thoughts. This should help you to understand what is going on in there.

And always remember: C++ needs numbers, not symbols. Whenever you have a symbol in an expression on your piece of paper that you do not know the value of you can either find a way how to compute the value out of the known values or you have to eliminate the need to compute using this symbol.

P.S.: It is not considered good style to post identical questions in [multiple](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=512766) discussion boards at once...

### Edit 2

Now you evaluate the function at point y=0.3. This is the way to go if you want to evaluate the polynomial. However, as you stated, you want all coefficients of the polynomial.

Again, I still feel you did not understand the math behind the problem. Maybe I will give you a small example. I am going to use the notation as it is used in the wikipedia article.

Suppose we had k=2 and x=-1, 1. Furthermore, let my just name your cos-Function f, for simplicity. (The notation will get rather ugly without latex...) Then the lagrangian polynomial is defined as

```
f(x_0) * l_0(x) + f(x_1)*l_1(x)
```

where (by doing the simplifications again *symbolically*)

```
l_0(x)= (x - x_1)/(x_0 - x_1) = -1/2 * (x-1) = -1/2 *x  + 1/2
l_1(x)= (x - x_0)/(x_1 - x_0) = 1/2 * (x+1)  = 1/2 * x  + 1/2
```

So, you lagrangian polynomial is

```
  f(x_0) * (-1/2 *x  + 1/2) + f(x_1) * 1/2 * x  + 1/2
= 1/2 * (f(x_1) - f(x_0)) * x     +     1/2 * (f(x_0) + f(x_1))
```

So, the coefficients you want to compute would be 1/2 * (f(x_1) - f(x_0)) and 1/2 * (f(x_0) + f(x_1)).

Your task is now to find an algorithm that does the simplification I did, but without using symbols. If you know how to compute the coefficients of the l_j, you are basically done, as you then just can add up those multiplied with the corresponding value of f.

So, even further broken down, you have to find a way to multiply the quotients in the l_j with each other on a *component-by-component* basis. Figure out how this is done and you are a nearly done.

### Edit 3

Okay, lets get a little bit less vague.

We first want to compute the L_i(x). Those are just products of linear functions. As said before, we have to represent each polynomial as an array of coefficients. For good style, I will use `std::vector` instead of this array. Then, we could define the data structure holding the coefficients of L_1(x) like this:

```
std::vector L1 = std::vector(5); 
// Lets assume our polynomial would then have the form 
// L1[0] + L2[1]*x^1 + L2[2]*x^2 + L2[3]*x^3 + L2[4]*x^4
```

Now we want to fill this polynomial with values.

```
// First we have start with the polynomial 1 (which is of degree 0)
// Therefore set L1 accordingly:
L1[0] = 1;
L1[1] = 0; L1[2] = 0; L1[3] = 0; L1[4] = 0;
// Of course you could do this more elegant (using std::vectors constructor, for example)
for (int i = 0; i < N+1; ++i) {
    if (i==0) continue;  /// For i=0, there will be no polynomial multiplication
    // Otherwise, we have to multiply L1 with the polynomial
    // (x - x[i]) / (x[0] - x[i])
    // First, note that (x[0] - x[i]) ist just a scalar; we will save it:
    double c = (x[0] - x[i]);
    // Now we multiply L_1 first with (x-x[1]). How does this multiplication change our 
    // coefficients? Easy enough: The coefficient of x^1 for example is just
    // L1[0] - L1[1] * x[1]. Other coefficients are done similary. Futhermore, we have
    // to divide by c, which leaves our coefficient as
    // (L1[0] - L1[1] * x[1])/c. Let's apply this to the vector:
    L1[4] = (L1[3] - L1[4] * x[1])/c;
    L1[3] = (L1[2] - L1[3] * x[1])/c;
    L1[2] = (L1[1] - L1[2] * x[1])/c;
    L1[1] = (L1[0] - L1[1] * x[1])/c;
    L1[0] = (      - L1[0] * x[1])/c; 
    // There we are, polynomial updated.
}
```

This, of course, has to be done for all L_i Afterwards, the L_i have to be added and multiplied with the function. That is for you to figure out. (Note that I made quite a lot of inefficient stuff up there, but I hope this helps you understanding the details better.)

Hopefully this gives you some idea how you could proceed.

Comment: :Ok,i understood what you said.I must have the polynomial approximation as numbers.For example,L1=...,L2=...Which is the term prod in my code.So, i am changing prod from double to pointer.See the edit above.But sth i am not doing right.

Comment: Maybe one other thing: Do you really want to give all coefficients for the lagrange polynomial or is it sufficient to be able to evaluate the function?

Comment: :Hello and thanks for helping.I updated my code.The problem now is that i can't take right values of lagrange coeff.It gives me "inf and 1".I tried to give different values for the "y"  but still the same problem.As for your question above what do you mean?If i find the coefficients don't i evaluate the function also?(And as for your P.S,i didn't have an answer so i posted here)

Comment: @Georg: Im currently on a rather tight schedule. I will answer as soon as my time permits, if nobody else did until then.

Comment: :Ok,i understand.(i updated my code ,its working now but my problem is with the value "y" the approximation.What value must i give to it?i can't understand because the exercise doesn't say "evaluate at the point ..."it says find the approximation.So, how can i do this?)

Comment: Edited my answer again, hope this helps. After you understood what I wrote I suggest looking at Howard's answer again, as this might give you the remaining clue you need.

Comment: :Hello and thanks for your time again.I really can't do anything more with my code.I did some small corrections but i can't do sth more.It just doesn't go..

Comment: As said before: You will not be able to get your code right until you understood *what* has to be done. I still would suggest that you first write down what you understood from a *mathematical* point of view. Afterwards we can look into that and try to get that right. Just working with the plain code won't help you understanding your problem. 
I could give you more explicit help how to get your code right, but you won't be able to understand it until you understood the basics. And, as I still think this is some kind of homework, it is about *understanding*, not about the solution.

Comment: :Hello.I have solved the exercise (because you said i didn't understod :)  ).The problem with the code is that it doesn't give me the coeff i figured from the exercise.And , i can't think what else to do..I understand the mathematic part but i can't imply it to the code.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved the mathematical part of the problem. What I feel is giving you trouble is taking the mathematical logic and forming it into an algorithm that you can implement. And this transformation also happens on the mathematical part of view, not in the code. If you would have understood this part, your code above would look very different. Still, I hope I helped you at least a bit.

Comment: I saw your image above just now (it somehow was to big to see...). My argument still is valid, however. As you can see, for example your L_1(x) is a polynomial of degree 4 and has 5 coefficients your computer has to compute. How would you get those coefficients? You have to implement the multiplication of those polynomials above manually. If I find the time I will give you a bit more to work with, probably I sould become less vague.

Comment: Okay, next edit ready. Hopefully, this helps more than the last, more vague hints.

Comment: :Thanks for your time Thilo.I will check tomorrow the details and see what can i do.(i will be missing for a week ,so maybe i 'll come back later)

Comment: :Hello,i came back and did some changes.I wanted to ask you if you can follow "my way" in the code,in order (for me )to understand it better.(I almost understand your point with edit 3).My mistake from the beginning was that i totally missed the every lagrange's values in order to have for every lagrange coeff a polynomial.That's why you were told to me to do the math :).Now, i updated my code , if you have any time and want to ,check it.If not i totally understand.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `y` is actually not a variable in your code but represents the variable `P(y)` of your lagrange approximation.

Thus, you have to understand the calculations `prod*=(y-x[i])/(x[k]-x[i])` and `sum+=prod*f` not directly but symbolically.

You may get around this by defining your approximation by a series

```
c[0] * y^0 + c[1] * y^1 + ...
```

represented by an array `c[]` within the code. Then you can e.g. implement multiplication

```
d = c * (y-x[i])/(x[k]-x[i])
```

coefficient-wise like

```
d[i] = -c[i]*x[i]/(x[k]-x[i]) + c[i-1]/(x[k]-x[i])
```

The same way you have to implement addition and assignments on a component basis.

The result will then always be the coefficients of your series representation in the variable `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few comments in addition to the existing responses.

> The exercise is: Find Lagrange's polynomial approximation for y(x)=cos(π x), x ∈ [-1,1] using 5 points (x = -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, and 1).

The first thing that your `main()` does is to ask for the degree of the polynomial. You should not be doing that. The degree of the polynomial is fully specified by the number of control points. In this case you should be constructing *the* unique fourth-order Lagrange polynomial that passes through the five points (x<sub>i</sub>, cos(π x<sub>i</sub>)), where the x<sub>i</sub> values are those five specified points.

> `const double pi=3.1415;`

This value is not good for a float, let alone a double. You should be using something like `const double pi=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288;`

Or better yet, don't use `pi` at all. You should know exactly what the y values are that correspond to the given x values. What are cos(-π), cos(-π/2), cos(0), cos(π/2), and cos(π)?

Comment: Hello.The exercise may specify the degree ,but i did it more generally.As you can see i ask the user to give the points of interpolation.And thanks for the advice.